# Would this recent MSE question be on topic on MESE?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728280/top-three-interesting-mathematical-problems-for-1st-year-university-students)'s the question mentioned in the title.

> Can you explain your top-three mathematical problems that you find the most interesting (NB: the problem must be accessible to a 1st year university student). Also, why do they interest you?

Is it on topic on MESE?

Comment: Retag appropriately, please.

Comment: This site is trying to steer away from big-list questions like this. If it were more focused (I.e. I'm teaching calculus and want students to be excited by interesting math problems that are somewhat accessible), it might be better.

Answer (score 2):

I find this to be entirely too broad. Better (in my opinion) would be a question like:

---

For those of you who have taught a first-year course in Calculus or Pre-Calculus, what are frequent student misconceptions you see regarding *continuous functions*, and what are examples of problems you use for the purpose of clarification?

Please include no more than three problems per post, and it would be best if you could explain *how* the problem addresses the misconception under discussion.

Answer (score 1):

No, this doesn't ask about teaching or learning or education.  As stated, the restriction to topics understandable by a first-year student seems arbitrary; the questions need more than a mention of that in a parenthetical *nota bene* to be on-topic here.